# Entityframework 4: Problem with ForeignKey when removing a child entity from parents collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

New to the EF, I have an issue.

OK, so, I have an Entity with a related Table (one-to-many relationship). The entity holds a collection of child objects from the related table.  I want to remove an object from the related collection but not from the child table.

However, when I call `<entity>.myRelatedChildTable.Remove( childEntity )` and then call the `_context.SaveChanges( )`, I get an exception about ForeignKey Constraints.  Now, if I call the `_context.DeleteObject()` and then `_context.SaveChanges()` we have no problem. But, now we have no child entity as well--it is deleted from the db.

here is the text of the Exception:
*The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one 
or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is 
made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null 
value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship 
must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null
value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.*

anyone have an idea/suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: It does sound like the exception is describing the exact problem... Does the SQL table with the foreign key allow null values for the key? If not the EF won't be able to delete the referenced row hence the exception.

Comment: It does not allow nulls, that is the problem (someone else owns the db and I can not change it). I need to remove it from the collection but not from the db w/o causing an exception. I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically trying to decouple EF from the database.  Unfortunately save changes pushes the changes back to the database which obviously you don't want.  You can just not call SaveChanges and continue to work with the collection.  EF will account for your deletion and not return that information.  At the end you can discard your changes and move on.

If you do actually want to delete the item without deleting the child you can't in the current schema.  You would have to allow nulls in the DB.

Comment: yeah, basically i want to remove it from the parents collection without removing the data from the database.  so that i can keep the row and it is no longer related to the row in the other table.

Comment: I don't think you current schema permits that...I am stuck in a similar situation